# [1]: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle11g

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
SELECT rh_party_branch
     , rh_doc_no
     , rh_batch_id
     , rh_cre_dt
     , rh_fc_amt
     , rh_mode_of_pay
     , rh_off_code
     , rh_narration
     , rh_status
     , rh_cre_user_init
     , get_policy_no(rh_doc_no)POLICY_NO
     , get_product(rh_doc_no )Product
     , get_class(rh_doc_no,rh_cre_dt)Class_of_bussines
  FROM APT_RCT_HEAD
```

Comment: Please add more details to the question, such as some sample data, expected output, and also the code for the various functions that are accessed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, one or more function out of  `get_policy_no, get_product, get_class` are having a subquery that is returning more than one row.

As a starting point you can look at the code of these functions where you are having some query as:

```
             select a,b,c from t where d=(select d from t2 where {conditions})
```

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: yes I have some functions below is one function get_policy_no (v_receipt_no VARCHAR2)  
return varchar2  is

v_polh_polnum  VARCHAR2(20) ;
begin

 select DISTINCT of_party_ref_no into  v_polh_polnum
from apt_open_file
where  of_sys_id = ( 

select ad_of_sys_id from apt_adj_detl , apt_adj_head
where ad_ah_sys_id = ah_sys_id
and ah_adj_no  = v_receipt_no
and ad_dr_cr = 'C');
return  v_polh_polnum ;
end ;

Comment: Please check if the query select ad_of_sys_id from apt_adj_detl , apt_adj_head where ad_ah_sys_id = ah_sys_id and ah_adj_no = v_receipt_no and ad_dr_cr = 'C' is giving single row or multiple rows for your input v_receipt_id

Comment: it gave invalid identifier at v_receipt

Comment: You will need to replace v_receipt with the value that you are passing in the functuion for running the query as SQL